# How to convert two rows value in a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below sql server query data

[image: Sample data]

Looking for solution.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    p.ProjectName,
    i.ItemName,
    inv.TransactionDirection,
    SUM(inv.TransactionQty) AS TransactionQuantity
 FROM INVTransaction inv
 JOIN BDProject p ON p.ProjectID=inv.ProjectID
 JOIN MDItem i ON i.ItemID=inv.ItemID
 GROUP BY p.ProjectName,
    i.ItemName,
    inv.TransactionDirection
```

Comment: Make two separate queries

Comment: Which Boolean condition?

Comment: @JaydipJ the TransactionDirection i'd say.

Comment: TransactionDirection

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.ProjectName, i.ItemName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv.TransactionDirection = 'IN' THEN inv.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) as IN_Quantity,
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv.TransactionDirection = 'OUT' THEN inv.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) as OUT_Quantity,
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv.TransactionDirection = 'IN' THEN inv.TransactionQty
                WHEN inv.TransactionDirection = 'OUT' THEN -inv.TransactionQty 
                ELSE 0
           END) as Balance
FROM INVTransaction inv JOIN
     BDProject p
     ON p.ProjectID = inv.ProjectID JOIN
     MDItem i ON i.ItemID = inv.ItemID
GROUP BY p.ProjectName, i.ItemName
```

Comment: Thank you, It's working fine except Balance column not providing correct differences.

Comment: You can use the query proposed by Gordon as the sub query, like this: `select *,  (IN_Quantity - OUT_Quantity) as Balance 
from (
SELECT inv.ProjectName, inv.ItemName, SUM(CASE WHEN inv.TransactionDirection = 'IN' THEN inv.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) as IN_Quantity,
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv.TransactionDirection = 'OUT' THEN inv.TransactionQty ELSE 0 END) as OUT_Quantity FROM (...) ) t`

Comment: @KayserAhmed . . . I had misunderstood the `Balance` calculation.  The query should do it correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot for this. Below is working query.

```
SELECT PROJECTNAME,ITEMNAME,[IN],[OUT] ,ISNULL([IN],0)-ISNULL([OUT],0) AS BALANCE FROM
(SELECT PROJECTNAME,ITEMNAME,TRANSACTIONDIRECTION,TRANSACTIONQUANTITY FROM TRANSACTIONS
)A
PIVOT (SUM(TRANSACTIONQUANTITY) FOR TRANSACTIONDIRECTION IN ([IN],[OUT])) AS PVT
```

Replace TRANSACTIONS with your table name

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff almost provided solution but for balance column you can replace

```
SUM(inv.TransactionQty) as Balance
```

With

```
SUM(CASE WHEN inv.TransactionDirection = 'IN' 
         THEN inv.TransactionQty 
         ELSE -1*inv.TransactionQty END) as Balance
```